# How to put date in function's parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have function that takes date as an argument and then turns it into a string but I get this error:

```
turn_date_into_str(24.09.1873)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It points to the second dot.
Here's my function:

```
def turn_date_into_str(date_as_dt: date):
    res = date_as_dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    return res
```

Is there a way to actually put date in function's argument?

Comment: `24.09.1873` is not valid, is this supposed to be a string?

Comment: no, it's supposed to be a date

Answer (score 2):

Create and pass date object correctly

```py
from datetime import date
date_obj = date(2022, 5, 8)
res = turn_date_into_str(date_obj)

print(res)
```